# Build only a SDK 6.1 app in Xcode 5

Tags: xcode, sdk, ide

I am using Xcode 5 to add features to an Xcode 4 iPad project. I have set the project to use the iOS 6.1 SDK in Xcode 5 because I am not ready to move to the 7.1 style interface.

When I attach an iPad Mini running iOS 7 to my development machine for testing, the Mini appears on my target selection list twice. One selection runs the app with the older 6.1 look (which I want) and the other runs the app with the new 7.1 look.

I would like to make sure that there is no way I can deliver (or even test) the app with the 7.1 look. I have already once made the mistake of delivering the app with a 7.1 interface. It was a disaster and I would like to make very sure that I don’t do it again.

I cannot seem to find a way to lock Xcode into the 6.1 SDK such that the 7.1 app version does not appear on my target list. I have no confidence that I cannot build a version with the 7.1 look.

Is there a way I can lock Xcode into building the app only with the 6.1 look, and that will remove the 7.1 target from my list?

Thanks

Comment: Ready or not you need to fully support iOS 7 now. Apple no longer accepts new apps or app updates unless they fully support iOS 7 with Xcode 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep In your mind

Starting February 1, new apps and app updates submitted to the App Store must be built with the latest version of Xcode 5 and must be optimized for iOS 7. Learn more about preparing your apps by reviewing the [iOS Human Interface Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/userexperience/conceptual/mobilehig/InteractivityInput.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006556-CH55-SW1).

Step 1:

[image]

Step 2: it is default iOS 7. so choose your deployment target 6.1

[image]

Step 3:

[image]

Comment: This appears backwards. You are showing a Deployment Target of 7.0 and a Base SDK of 6.1. As of now you need a Base SDK of 7.0 while the Deployment Target can be whatever is appropriate for the app.

Comment: step 2 is list out what are the target is available. then the user going to choose iOS 6.1 from the list

Comment: It would be clearer if the screen shots showed what the user should be selecting.

Comment: OK but the 3rd step still shows the wrong Base SDK.

Comment: now how is it...it should be ok else need any changes